# how we display values in textfields in jsp

Tags: javascript, database, jsp

i want to display values in text fields in jsp. i have fetched value from database in jsp page now i want to display in text fields onblur method call.

```
    <%!Connection con; %>
<%!Statement s; %>
<%!ResultSet rs; %>
<% String cnic=request.getParameter("id");
try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test","root","");
s=con.createStatement();
rs=s.executeQuery("select * from info where cnic='"+cnic+"'");
}catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
%>

<% while(rs.next()) 
{ %>

<%=rs.getString("first_name")%>
<%=rs.getString("last_name")%>
<%=rs.getString("gender")%>
<%=rs.getString("cnic")%>
<%=rs.getString("date_of_birth")%>
<%=rs.getString("institute")%>
<%=rs.getString("department")%>
<%=rs.getString("degree_level")%>
<%=rs.getString("programe")%>
<%=rs.getString("year")%>

<% } %>

    <input type="text" onblur="Ajax(this.value);" />
    <input type="text"  />
    <input type="text" />
```

how we display value in these text fields

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this

```
<input type="text" value="<%=yourExpression%>"/>
```

Comment: it is not working  because while loop end above and we cannot access out of loop

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to display a single set of boxes or one set of boxes per result set row? 

Please add more explanation.